# Why does openpyxl read a list as unicode?

Tags: python, excel, list, unicode, openpyxl

I am using the `openpyxl` library to read data from an Excel sheet.  A sample cell might contains a list like `[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]`, an integer like `5`, or a string like `sample string`.

The integer is correctly read as an integer, but the strings and lists are both read as unicode:

```
print "{} is {}".format(data, type(data))
```

yields

```
5 is <type 'int'>
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]] is <type 'unicode'>
sample string is <type 'unicode'>
```

I would like to prevent the lists from being read as unicode, or find a fix for converting unicode to lists and strings appropriately.

Here is an unsuccessful attempt to fix this:

```
def remove_unicode(data):
    if isinstance(data, unicode):
    return data.encode('utf-8')
```

Of course, the problem with this is that lists are returned as strings.  I could improve this by changing the type to list if the first and last characters in the returned string are`[` and `]`, but that seems clunky.   I suspect that a better solution would be to prevent my lists and strings from being read as unicode in the first place.

Comment: Just to be clear, it sounds like you think that there are lists as a basic Excel type and they're being misinterpreted by Python as strings.  Is that right?

Comment: @DSM I'm not expecting that lists are a basic Excel type.  What I am expecting is that openpyxl will interpret a cell containing something like `[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]` as a list when importing into the Python environment.  Instead it seems to be interpreting it as unicode.  My assumption is probably incorrect, and is almost certainly causing the issue that I'm experiencing.

Comment: According to the specification a cell's data type can be a number, a boolean, a string, a formula or an error. It can, in theory, even be a datetime. There is, however, no compound data type such as an array. What are you asking for is like saying x = '[1, 2, 3]'  and expecting Python to see treat x as a list. It doesn't and for very good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A sample cell might contains a list like [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]

It can't contain a list like that, given that lists are not an Excel data type.  What you have is simply a string, and openpyxl is correctly interpreting it as one, rather than trying to guess whether or not you want it interpreted as an object somehow encoded.  (See the Zen: "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.")

If you want to convert something which looks like the string representation of a Python list of integers to a list, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> sheet
<Worksheet "Sheet1">
>>> sheet.cell("A1").value
'[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]'
>>> type(_)
<class 'str'>
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(sheet.cell("A1").value)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> type(_)
<class 'list'>
```

or (in this case, anyway) `json.loads`.  Note that I get `str` as the datatype and not `unicode` because I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Perfect - this makes clear which of my assumptions was incorrect and how to fix it.